# How to get data from multiple form elements within a single view

Tags: cakephp, controller, view

I have added three form elements

1. defineroute.ctp
2. singleroute.ctp
3. singletrip.ctp
   in a view called route.ctp.there is a function for the route.ctp in the users_controller called route().
   my doubt is how to manage the data coming from these three elements and store it in different tables. how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sibin,

There are many ways to do it.

1. As you have separate elements that menas you have create different-different form tags for all different form and once they are submitted then it will go to specific controller and action so it is very simple here.
2. If you have kept one form tag for all your element then you can keep your text boxes name different for different-different models.

like:

For defineroute.ctp

data[model1][field1]
data[model1][field2]

singleroute.ctp
data[model2][field1]
data[model2][field2]

singletrip.ct

data[model3][field1]
data[model3][field2]

Once they form is submitted then you will one array containing different model array like:

data[model1]=>array(field1, field2)
data[model2]=>array(field1, field2)
data[model3]=>array(field1, field2)

Now you can perform save action and enjoy madi!!!

Comment: first of all thanks for your great reply. in my users_controller it is necessery for create 3 actions for three elemets forms? or how can  manage these three form element data with route() method.can u please show me one example to how to do this? im very beginer in cakephp platform..